# How do I plug a boost::random QRNG into a C++ standard distribution?

Tags: c++, random, c++23, boost-random

I'm trying to use a `boost::random::sobol` QRNG to sample one of the standard C++ distributions listed here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random, but the results are not correct.

Suppose I wish to sample a binomial distribution. According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/binomial_distribution, I can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>

int main()
{
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());  // <-- PRNG

  // perform 4 trials, each succeeds 1 in 2 times
  std::binomial_distribution<> d(4, 0.5);

  std::map<int, int> hist;
  for (int n = 0; n != 10000; ++n)
    ++hist[d(gen)];

  for (auto const& [x, y] : hist)
    std::cout << x << ' ' << std::string(y / 100, '*') << '\n';
}
```

and that works well, producing output something like this:

```
0 ******
1 *************************
2 *************************************
3 ************************
4 *****
```

However, I want to use a quasi-random number generator (in particular, a `boost::random::sobol`). If I've understood the documentation and the hints in [Running std::normal_distribution with user-defined random generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178647/running-stdnormal-distribution-with-user-defined-random-generator) (unfortunately, that page includes a dead link to what looks like a code example :/) correctly (and clearly I haven't), I can adapt my code above, and do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <boost/random/sobol.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::random::sobol gen(1);  // QRNG: 1D sobol sequence
  gen.seed(237);  // just set the seed to something

  // perform 4 trials, each succeeds 1 in 2 times
  std::binomial_distribution<> d(4, 0.5);

  std::map<int, int> hist;
  for (int n = 0; n != 10000; ++n)
    ++hist[d(gen)];  // <-- plug the QRNG in here

  for (auto const& [x, y] : hist)
    std::cout << x << ' ' << std::string(y / 100, '*') << '\n';
}
```

This code runs, which (I think) means that the `boost::random::sobol` satisfies the requirements of the `uniform_random_bit_generator` concept, but the results this time are:

```
2 ****************************************************************************************************
```

which is clearly wrong (I've tried a bunch of standard distributions and they all look similarly awful). So I've obviously misunderstood something. Any advice very much appreciated.

If it makes any difference, I'm working in Windows with the latest version of C++ (I think it's the experimental C++23) in Visual Studio, and use boost 1.80.

Comment: @PeteBecker I've added all of the necessary `#include`'s and wrapped the code in a main(). Both snippets now compile and run as complete programmes on my machine.

Comment: I don't know enough details to give a proper answer but I'm fairly certain that it will work if you switch out `std::binomial_distribution` for `boost::binomial_distribution` when using `sobol` (or indeed *any* Boost generator, if my hunch is correct). Something about stdlib distributions operating over `UniformRandomBitGenerator`s while Boost distributions operate over `UniformRandomNumberGenerator`s... (Very similar syntactic requirements but differing _semantic_ requirements)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be dependent on the library implementation of the distribution, and in general you cannot expect this to work - whether with boost or std. By definition, a sequence of numbers obtained from a QRNG is not random or uniform - it is required to have low discrepancy.

For example, if I follow the definition of the binomial distribution literally and perform 4 trials using 4 numbers drawn from the distribution like so:

```cpp
  const auto cutoff = gen.max() / 2;

  std::map<int, int> hist;
  for (int n = 0; n != 10000; ++n) {
    int passes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        passes += (gen() <= cutoff);
    }
    ++hist[passes];
  }
```

Then we get the output you report - and it's easy to see why: the "low-discrepancy" part means that half of the four numbers drawn are likely in the first half of the range (so the trial succeeds) and the remaining half of them are in the second half. (This, incidentally, is how MSVC implements `binomial_distribution` for small numbers of trials.)

Now, this works if the distribution consumes one number from the engine per number generated (typical for inverse transform sampling); this is the case for `boost::binomial_distribution` if the number of expected successes is small, but is generally not the case for arbitrary distributions.